# How can i combine several database files with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I know that I can can read a file with numpy with the genfromtxt command. It works like this:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('bmrbtmp',unpack=True,names=True,dtype=None)
```

I can plot the stuff in there easily with:

```
ax.plot(data['field'],data['field2'], linestyle=" ",color="red")
```

or

```
ax.boxplot(data)
```

and its awesome. What I really would like to do now is read a whole folder of files and combine them into one giant dataset. How do I add datapoints to the data data structure?
And how do I read a whole folder at once?

Comment: Do all the files have the same format? (The same header and number of columns?)

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the arrays?

Comment: yeah all files and header the same

Comment: i dont know how array concatenation works on numpy arrays

Comment: not really a numpy user, but it seems it's one function - [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To visit all the files in a directory, use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

To stack two structured numpy arrays "vertically", use [np.vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).

To save the result, use [np.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to save in a text format, or [np.save](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) to save the array in a (smaller) binary format.

---

```
import os
import numpy as np

result = None
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown = True):
    for filename in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r') as f:
            data = np.genfromtxt(f, unpack=True, names=True, dtype=None)
        if result is None:
            result = data
        else:
            result = np.vstack((result, data))

print(result[:10]) # print first 10 lines
np.save('/tmp/outfile.npy', result)
```